# How come Function is not getting execute even if correct syntax

Tags: javascript, function

I have created a function that receive an array of Student details an display it. But it's executing  properly. May be i'm missing something. Thanks in advance.

```js
function displayData(stdDetails) {

  for (var t in stdDetails) //printing keys along with values
  {
    console.log("in loop");
    console.log(t, ":", stdDetails[t]);

    if (typeof(stdDetails[t]) == 'object') {
      displayData(stdDetails[t]);
    }
  }

}
displayData();
```

Comment: What is `stdDetails`?

Comment: You are passing nothing into the function.

Comment: What is happening that is not what you are expecting?

Comment: `function displayData(stdDetails)  { if (!stdDetails) { alert("You did not pass anything"); return } ....`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

displayData() requires stdDetails argument, which you are not providing to it.

Comment: Can't we just close this as "typo type" ? _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced_ and answered in the comments

Comment: i've created stdDetails object in that program but not able to use that